# =filter function for Excel like in Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: excel

I had this formula in GoogleSpreadsheets: `=filter(A1:C, A1:A=1)`

But obviously I cannot use that in Excel.

Is there an alternative way of doing this using a formula in Excel, without a macro or script?

What I am trying to do is Find a cell containing specific text, and copy that row to new columns.

```
Say I have columns A,B, and C

A1= 1   B1= xxx  C1=xxx
A2= 2   B2= xxx  C2=xxx
A3= 1   B3= xxx  C3=xxx

I would like to search for "1" in column A and return the match's entire row to say E,F, and G. 

So,  A1 B1 and C1 and A3 B3 and C3 would be displayed in E1:G1 and E2:G2 respectively.
```

EDIT: This is my actual sheet below, I was just trying to keep it simple, by using my text example. My formula seems just about there to achieving my result, but something is still a bit off. "=IFERROR(INDEX(A$2:A$200,SMALL(IF($D$2:$D$200="WR",ROW($A$2:$A$200)-1),ROWS(A2:A2))),"")"

[image]

Comment: I'm not familiar with what that function does in google spreadsheets - could you clarify?

Comment: =FILTER - Returns a filtered version of the source range, returning only rows or columns which meet the specified conditions.

Answer (score 3):

in E1

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$C$15,SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$15=$K$1,ROW($A$1:$A$15)-ROW($A$1)+1,""),ROWS($A$1:A1)),COLUMN(A1)),"")
```

Enter with Ctrl+Shift+Enter

Copy across to G and down

K1 contains the "search" value for column A i.e. 1